# Can I have expanded one node only on load in Tabulator.js?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using [nested data trees](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.9#tree) in Tabulator.js and if I use the option `dataTreeStartExpanded:true` all nested rows will be expanded. I want only one be expanded on load/render? Is that possible?

Here is working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/8szy9tug/12/) to play around.

I found that there is a div with class `tabulator-data-tree-control-expand` or `tabulator-data-tree-control-collapse`. Changing the name in dev tools does nothing.

Currently it looks like [image]

But I want to be like that after the web page loads [image]

Maybe I can somehow click the `+` to expand. Tabulator has a listener there [image]

But I do not know how to call it for that particular +.

Answer (score 0):

oh, I found it in [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/tree#layout-state).

.. a function that will be passed in a row component and the level of that row in the table (starting at 0), it should return a boolean value to indicate the rows expansion state:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    dataTree:true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded:function(row, level){
        return row.getData().driver; //expand rows where the "driver" data field is true;
    },
});
```

and then in data you have to use new property `driver:true`